# JARS necessary to distribute Eclipse EMF based library?

Tags: eclipse, jar, distribution, eclipse-emf

I'm working with a library (MDHT from OpenHealthTools) to parse `CDA XML`.
It relies on parts of Eclipse and the EMF plugin for Eclipse to do its thing. I've addressed most of the dependencies, but I'm still running into this error:

```
Could not initialize class org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform
        at org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.internal.registry.CDARegistry.load(CDARegistry.java:41)
        at org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.internal.registry.CDARegistry.getEClass(CDARegistry.java:67)
        at org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.internal.resource.CDALoadImpl.handleTemplate(CDALoadImpl.java:144)
        at org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.internal.resource.CDALoadImpl.processNode(CDALoadImpl.java:110)
        at org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.internal.resource.CDALoadImpl.traverse(CDALoadImpl.java:94)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.traverse(XMLLoadImpl.java:555)
        at org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.internal.resource.CDALoadImpl.traverse(CDALoadImpl.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:406)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:615)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.load(XMLResourceImpl.java:579)
        at org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.util.CDAUtil.load(CDAUtil.java:66)
        at org.openhealthtools.mdht.uml.cda.util.CDAUtil.load(CDAUtil.java:58)
        at com.mirth.results.models.serializer.CDAConverter.convertCDAToClinicalDocumentModel(CDAConverter.java:23)
        at com.mirth.results.models.serializer.CDAConverterTest.testConvertCDAToClinicalDocumentModel(CDAConverterTest.java:42)


Java Result: 2
```

I have placed the `JAR` from Eclipse with `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform` on the classpath. Does it have additional dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and see if a [similar set of core eclipse plugins used for ATL](http://wiki.eclipse.org/ATL_Howtos#ATL) could be needed for your MDHT plugin as well.
Especially:

```
Eclipse libraries

    * org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.3.*.jar
    * org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.3.*.jar
    * org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility_3.*.jar
    * org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.3.*.jar
    * org.eclipse.core.resources_3.3.*.jar
    * org.eclipse.osgi_3.3.*.jar
```

(Note: this is a bit old -- eclipse 3.3 -- so you need to adapt that list to the version of eclipse you are running)

Comment: That plus an equiniox.registry JAR did it. Thx!

Comment: Thanks so much. This also works for BPEL Model Plugin and that too in eclipse version 3.8.1